# Numbers not expressible as a sum of an arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory

> For every integer $d \geq 1$, let $M_d$ be the set of all positive integers that cannot be written as a sum of an arithmetic progression with difference $d$, having at least two terms and consisting of positive integers. Let $A = M_1, B = M_2 \smallsetminus \{2\}, C = M_3$. Prove that every $c \in C$ may be written in a unique way $c = ab$ with $a \in A, b \in B$.

I don't see how in the below they can say "for every $x$ with an odd divisor $p>3$ it is easy to see that there exist corresponding $a,n$." Firstly, don't they mean $p \geq 3$ and secondly how is it easy to see there exist corresponding $a,n$?

**Book's partial solution:**

[image]

Comment: For $a=n=2$ we have $x=\frac{2\cdot (2\cdot 2+2-1) }{2}=5$ Thus $p=5>3$.

Comment: @callculus I don't see what one example shows.

Comment: I shows that $p>3$ for $a,n \geq 2$

Comment: @callculus We could have some number larger with a factor of $3$.

Comment: The odd factors increase if a,n increase. Maybe one odd factor can be 9. But this doesn´t mean that you can divide it in odd two factors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they should say odd divisor $p \ge 3$.  If $3|x$ the progression can be $\frac x3-1, \frac x3, \frac x3+1$.  Specifically, if $x=3$ the term $\frac x3-1$ is zero, which is not permitted, but we can just delete it and have the progression $1,2$  This shows how to deal with any odd divisor $p$ (which need not be prime).  The progression is $\frac xp-\frac {p-1}2, \frac xp-\frac {p-1}2+1, \frac xp-\frac {p-1}2+2 \dots \frac xp+\frac {p-1}2$, so $a=\frac xp-\frac {p-1}2, n=p$ This has $p$ terms which average $\frac xp$, so sum $p$.  What can go wrong is that $a=\frac xp-\frac {p-1}2 \lt 0$.  If so, you can delete the terms from $\frac xp-\frac {p-1}2$ through $-\frac xp+\frac {p-1}2$ as they sum to zero.  If we had $x=11$, the original series would be $-4, -3, -2, \dots , 4,5,6$.  We can delete the first nine terms, which sum to zero, and be left with $5,6$.  This works for any odd number and is guaranteed to leave us two terms.

Comment: How do you know that $a$ is always a positive integer if $a = \frac{x}{p} - \frac{p-1}{2}$?

Comment: If not, you can delete the terms that are negative and the matching ones that are positive.  I'll add that in.

Comment: Where is $-\frac{x}{p}+\frac{p-1}{2}$ coming from?

Comment: It is the negative of the other term.  We delete as many positive terms as negative terms, so the deleted terms sum to zero and the sum of the series stays the same.